# How do I make an arrayformula apply an existing arrayformula to a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

EDIT: I had no idea the link to my main sheet was linking to the image instead of my sample workbook, I've realized my mistake thanks to @horanimal and the link has been corrected.

I'm using an arrayformula on my [Main sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14K7yyhyn4PmUupxdznnFRGraeiMCnOwRi1UjZh5_TBA/edit?usp=sharing) to populate cells with filtered data from my Info sheet based on dates in Column A. This formula counts the number of matches on the Info sheet defined by the Main sheet data in Cells B2 and B3 which correspond to the date in Column A, which have either the status of PASS or REPAIRED, and then multiplies that amount by a number in the Data sheet, finally subtracting the sum of any applicable numbers on the Info sheet for the final result.

Main Sheet:

[image]

Info Sheet:

[image]

I've written this formula for Cell B4 and copied it down the column: `=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Info!$A$5:$5,Info!$A$2:$2=$A4,Info!$A$3:$3=$B$2,Info!$A$4:$4="➕",REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED"))))*Data!$B$4 -SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Info!$A$8:$8,Info!$A$2:$2=$A4,Info!$A$3:$3=$B$2,Info!$A$4:$4="➕",REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED")))))`

This is giving me the correct data, but what I am trying to accomplish is to have only a single formula in Cell B3 process the entire column and give me the same data. I've tried to rewrite the formula this way for Cell C3, but I'm only getting the first result in Cell C4, while the cells in C5:C remain blank:
`={"➕➕";ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(Info!A$5:$5,Info!A$2:$2=$A4,Info!A$3:$3=$B$2,Info!A$4:$4="➕➕",REGEXMATCH(Info!A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),REGEXMATCH(Info!A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED"))))*Data!$B$4 -SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Info!A$8:$8,Info!A$2:$2=$A4,Info!A$3:$3=$B$2,Info!A$4:$4="➕➕",REGEXMATCH(Info!A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),REGEXMATCH(Info!A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED")))))}`

How would I rewrite this correctly using only one formula?

Comment: Please add some additional data on your question such as a sample *dummy sheet file* for replication. Kindly review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you.

Comment: @J.Kubassek can you provide some example headers & values for the `Info` table?

Comment: Please see my updated post, I did not realize that the link for my example sheet was not pointing to the correct location.

Comment: **check out answer below, I think we've got it!** *Also once we solve this I'd LOVE to know what this is for & why you're going horizontally with the dates in the `Info` table instead of vertically* :)

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! And this is for tracking daily production values per station with a few product filters in place. As for why the Info table is horizontal - that's simply because it was most efficient to set up the data entry that way and the data in my actual sheet is just being fed to that sheet in the same format as it is entered - but it could also be imported horizontally if that makes creating formulas easier, I hadn't actually thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first formula is great, you just need to adjust it slightly to utilize the `BYROW` function, like so:

```
=BYROW(A4:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",ARRAYFORMULA(
  COUNTA(
    IFERROR(
      FILTER(
        Info!$A$5:$5,
        Info!$A$2:$2=r,
        Info!$A$3:$3=$B$2,
        Info!$A$4:$4="➕",
        REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),
        REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED")
      )
    )
  )*Data!$B$4-SUM(
    IFERROR(
      FILTER(
        Info!$A$8:$8,
        Info!$A$2:$2=r,
        Info!$A$3:$3=$B$2,
        Info!$A$4:$4="➕",
        REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$6:$6,"PASS|REPAIRED"),
        REGEXMATCH(Info!$A$7:$7,"PASS|REPAIRED")
      )
    )
  )
))))
```

All I did was add `BYROW(A4:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",` in front of your ARRAYFORMULA, then wherever you had `$A4` I changed it to `r`.

Basically what this does is it cycles through every row in the range you specify (A4:A) so instead of dragging down manually it will just pull for every non-empty cell in A4:A.